# Hashing SHA-256 for C# and Java

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, sha, message-digest

I needed to generate the hash in Java and then check it in C#. How to get the same output from these two algorithms when converting back to a string?

------------C#------------

```
    ?
```

------------Java------------

```
public static String encrypt(String value) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    private static final String ALGORITHM = "SHA-256";
    private static final String[] UPDATES = "goKpRF61ApDDJN9m0OOwHtU9G56psEqJjPUdiH3kZto=";

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(ALGORITHM);

    for (int i = 0; i < UPDATES.length; i++) {
        md.update(UPDATES[i].getBytes());
    }

    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(md.digest(value.getBytes()));
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you wanto to compute a hash of encoded input,  not raw? As well try to put some effort of your own into c# code, then maybe someone will help you further. Next - what do you mean by `converting back to a string?`?

Answer (score 0):

Let me comment on the Java part of your question (I don't know C#).

```
private static final String[] UPDATES = "goKpRF61ApDDJN9m0OOwHtU9G56psEqJjPUdiH3kZto=";
```

This does not look right. If you have just one string, the declaration should be:

```
private static final String UPDATES = "goKpRF61ApDDJN9m0OOwHtU9G56psEqJjPUdiH3kZto=";
```

And the rest of the code:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(ALGORITHM);

md.update(UPDATES.getBytes());

return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(md.digest());
```

If you have multiple strings to digest:

```
MessageDigest          md = MessageDigest.getInstance(ALGORITHM) ;
String                 str[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D"} ;

for (String s : str)
    md.update(s.getBytes()) ;

return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(md.digest());
```

(I ignored the Base64 bit because there are way too many Base64 libraries and I am guessing that you are using one that works alright)

Comment: Thank you for your comment and I will edit it to my java code. I want to change from Java Code -> C# Code

Comment: Hi . Do you found your c# code for decryption.I think between these two must be have a unique token inserted in web config.If you found your answer please say us.I have this problem